# Error on Installing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, installation

After I install mongodb via homebrew, I get the following message when I type mongod:

```
kamflamenco ~ $ mongod
2016-08-02T15:34:39.934-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4167 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Kenzos-MacBook-Pro.local
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-08-02T15:34:39.935-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-08-02T15:34:39.936-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-08-02T15:34:39.938-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2016-08-02T15:34:39.938-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I am new to this and I've tried researching on the error. However, I have no luck, including typing

```
sudo chmod 777
```

The only time mongod works is if I type sudo in front of it

```
sudo mongod
```

But I do not feel this is correct...

Comment: You need to check file ownership and permissions. Please run "ls -la /data/db/mongod.lock" and provide the output.

Answer (score 1):

remove the mongod.lock file:

```
sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock
```